# Calling XMLHTTPRequest from outside javascript

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I need to parse the content resulting from a XMLHttpRequest, not from the browser but using PHP/or PERL or whatever, BUT javascript.So I tried to  make a POST based on my understanding of the specific request I need to parse but I get  in return a 404 (page not found). 
Where is my mistake?
1) Incorrect post message
2) The server understands that my request is not coming from XMLHttprequest and then rejects with a 404.
3) Other I do not know.

Sorry, I cannot post the URL because it is inside the Intranet.

I will post the code written in perl:

```
use CGI;
use LWP::UserAgent; 
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;

my $response
= $ua->post( $myUrl, 
{ bId => '5', 
'c0id' => '0',
'c0mN' => 'cM',
'c0p0' => 'string3.57',
'c0p1' => 'boolean:false',
'c0sN' => 'mD',
'cC' => '1',
'httpSessionId' => '0C23946319623A',
'page' => $relPage,
'scriptSessionId' => '67233543259'
})
```

Comment: We don't need the URL, we need your code.

Comment: OK, found the solution: it was a sintax error  on line 'c0p0' => 'string3.57',; it should be corrected in 'c0p0' => 'string:3.57',

Answer (score 0):

> You don't have to do anything special with those other methods; just set the request type in the open() call, and send() an appropriate body (the item you're putting in the case of "PUT"; a null argument in the case of "GET").

Do you have a timeout mechanism and event scheduling in place?